# Can someone explain this anecdote from Bob Weinstock?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In this [interesting essay](http://www.utpa.edu/avid/Documents/Research/Studying_Students_Studying_Calculus_A_Look_at_the_lives_of_minority_mathematics_students_in_college.pdf) explaining the performance gap among minorities in elite universities, there is an anecdote at the very bottom of the essay which intrigued me. Here's the screenshot:

[image: Gather; Don't Strew, by Bob Weinstock]

I feel left out of the joke. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is similar to:

Question:) How much is $500 \times 10^3$?

Answer1:) $500 \times 10^3 = 500 \times (9+1)^3 = 5(9^3 + 3\times 9^2 + 3\times 9 + 1) \dots = $

Answer2:) It is $500 \times 1000 = 1000 + 1000 + \dots = $

The point is the integral can be evaluated *easily* as

$\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^3 \text{ d}x = -(1-x)^4/4 |_0^1 = -(1-1)^4/4 + (1-0)^4/4 = 1/4$

The joke is that most students did it the hard way by expanding $(1-x)^3$, while one student, computed the anti-derivative easily (giving some hope to the teacher), but then made it even harder by trying to expand that instead of just plugging in the values...

Comment: Ah! Now I see it, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The joke is that although the student integrated the function using substitution to get $\frac{(1-x)^4}{4}$ instead of substituting the limits of integration directly into this compact form he multiplied it out and made significantly more work for himself.