# Evaluating Integral $\int e^{x}(1-e^x)(1+e^x)^{10} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this integral to evaluate: $$\int e^{x}(1-e^x)(1+e^x)^{10} dx$$

I figured to use u substitution for the part that is raised to the tenth power. After doing this the $e^x$ is canceled out.

I am not sure where to go from here however due to the $(1-e^x)$.

Is it possible to move it to the outside like this and continue from here with evaluating the integral?

$$(1-e^x)\int u^{10} du$$

Comment: $1-e^x=2-(1+e^x)$

Comment: No, we cannot move it outside, it is not a constant. Let $u=1+e^x$. Then $du=e^x\,dx$ and since $e^x=u-1$, we find that $1-e^x=1-(u-1)=2-u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u=1+e^x$, then $e^x=u-1$, so $1-e^x=1-(u-1)=2-u$. Now you can easily multiply out. Note that the ‘bad’ factor could be any simple polynomial in $e^x$, and the technique would still work. For instance, if the integrand had been $e^x(3e^{2x}-4e^x+5)(1+e^x)^{10}$, substituting $u=1+e^x$ would turn it into $(3u^2-2u+4)u^{10}$, since

$$\begin{align*}
3e^{2x}-4e^x+5&=3(u-1)^2+4(u-1)+5\\
&=3u^2-2u+4\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=e^x$, $du=e^xdx$, so your integral is

$$\int (1-u)(1+u)^{10}du.$$

Now there are many ways for you to proceed (the quickest probably being integration by parts).

**Addendum**: to prove my claim that the quickest way is by parts, here it is:

$$\int (1-u)(1+u)^{10}du = \int(1-u)d\left(\frac{(1+u)^{11}}{11}\right) =$$

$$(1-u)\left(\frac{(1+u)^{11}}{11}\right) + \int \frac{(1+u)^{11}}{11} du = \frac{(1-u)(1+u)^{11}}{11}+\frac{(1+u)^{12}}{132}+C.$$

I challenge anyone (*cough! cough!* :-)) to do it quicker by expanding $(1+u)^{10}$.

Comment: The quickest way is just to do it. It's a polynomial after all.

Comment: You mean expanding $(1+u)^10$?

Comment: yeah. $         {}{}{}       $

Comment: Pretty sure it's quicker by parts! I'll race you if you want. :)

Comment: I think it will depend on whether or not you know the binomial formula. If you do, it's instantaneous.

Comment: I do not think that word means what you think that it means. @jspecter

Comment: @jspecter, feel free to append your instantaneous to the end of my post!

Comment: @Bruno, Your challenge reminds me of [this anecdote of Bob Weinstock](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61111/13425). :-)

Comment: @Srivatsan, thanks for sharing, I LOL'ed!

Answer (score 0):

let $x=\ln(u)$

$dx=du/u$

$I=\int e^{x}(1-e^x)(1+e^x)^{10} dx$ = $\int ((u(1-u)(1+u)^{10})/u)du$=$\int (1-u)(1+u)^{10}du$

You may want to take it from here...

Answer (score 0):

FWIFs, this also would be easily generalized via a recurrence relation (aside from the obvious substitution that confirms this] as the integral is of the form;

f ' (x) times g(x) (where f(x) is (1/11)(1+e^x)^11) and f(x), g(x) both behave good enough - i.e. we get back something close enough to our integral the define a recurrence.